# Docker-compose in Azure - DNS not working

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm trying to deploy a docker-compose file in Azure, my compose file looks like the below.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - misp-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=*****
      - MYSQL_USER=*****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=********
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=********
  web:
    image: *****
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - misp-web:/var/www/MISP
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
      - MYSQL_USER=*****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=************
```

When I deploy this to Azure, both containers start and run, as well as a third container 'aci--dns--sidecar', which I assume is for DNS resolution. However, from within the web container, it's impossible to resolve the DB container for me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

When you run multiple containers in the Azure Web App, there is only one container you can expose to the outside, and the port only can be one the 80 or 443. And inside the Web App, the containers can communicate with each via the container name and the port that it's exposed. For yours, you can access the DB container with the `db:port` from the web container, and I recommend you export the port which the DB needs to use first.

Comment: Hi,

I'm not using Azure Web App for this, but the regular container setup. Whenever I try to set up a database connection, I get this error:

"ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (2)"

which suggests it cannot find db. Also manual attempts to resolve the hostname fail.

Comment: @StevenGoossens What service do you use? You should set environment variables for the database connection.

Comment: Hi,

I'm aware, I just redacted them from the initial post. I've edited it now, but the problem remains that I can't connect to the database server when I use 'db' as the hostname. If I use the random generated hostname of the container, the connection does work.

When I deploy the same docker-compose file on a regular machine with docker installed, it works, so I still believe the problem has to do something with the ways Azure translates the docker-compose.

Comment: @StevenGoossens You can take a look at the example for docker-compose in Azure Web App [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container). It sets the depends_on and the environment variables for the db. Maybe the depdens_on makes sense for you.